# Should I install Webmin before LAMP

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, xampp

**As a total beginner, should I installed Webmin THEN LAMP or LAMP and THEN Webmin please?**

History:- *(I installed XAMPP a while ago - it worked though it never installed an ICON in the Applications. I decided to install Webmin as many folks suggested this as a good way to control Apache2 and MySQL etc. Installation went well but under "Server" in Webmin, there was no sign of Apache2 or MySQL server.

After searching, I found some people ADAMANT that I should use LAMP not XAMPP for security reasons and that Webmin should be installed first - others said LAMP/XAMPP must be installed first and THEN Webmin.
As I have made a pigs ear out of things, I have done a clean install so there is nothing messy to sort out. I just want to get the order right now.)*

**So, LAMP and THEN Webmin or Webmin and THEN LAMP please for the simplest installation for a beginner?**

Answer (score 1):

Webmin uses an existing Apache installation, so you will want to have the "LA" bit in LAMP before Webmin will work.

Basic prerequisites can be considered as:

1. an Ubuntu 20.04 server with a non-root user with sudo privileges
2. UFW firewall configured
3. Apache
4. a Fully-Qualified Domain Name (FQDN), with a DNS A record pointing to the IP address of your system

Be sure to have port 10000 available, otherwise you will not be able to connect to Webmin:

```
sudo ufw allow 10000
```